# LB 4.1: uid is not installed

Tags: logicblox, logiql

I am trying to use the unique id as described in the [Reference Manual](https://developer.logicblox.com/content/docs4/core-reference/webhelp/builtin-predicates.html#uid_p2p). However, I get the following error:

```
Error: P2PMapping defined at block_1Z1C1O1V:4(2)--7(73) requests module 'uid', but no module with that name is installed.
```

How do I install this module?

Answer (score 1):

What is your program, exactly? I just tried the following lb script (which is a simplified version of the example from the manual):

```
create --unique

addblock <doc>
  F[x] = id -> string(x), int(id).
  R(x) -> string(x).

  R("Joe").
  R("Jill").
</doc>

exec <doc>
  +F[x] = id <- uid<<id>> R(x).
</doc>
print F

close --destroy
```

The result is, as expected:

```
created workspace 'unique_workspace_2016-11-20-21-12-30'
added block 'block_1Z1B38XS'
"Jill" 10000000044
"Joe"  10000000046
deleted workspace 'unique_workspace_2016-11-20-21-12-30'
```